# insert child to XML that is saved as a String

Tags: php, xml, php-5.6

I'm working in PHP, I have a large XML saved in a String,I want to insert as a first child a node, I know the name of the parent, is something like:

```
<mytag Someattributte="anything">
   here I want to put my tag
...
a lot of tags
...
</mytag>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With DOM you use Xpath to fetch nodes, DOM document methods to create new nodes (`DOMDocument::createDocumentFragment()`) and DOM node methods to insert/append them (`DOMDocument::insertBefore()`).

Document fragments are a construct that allows you to treat a list of nodes as a single node. And they can load an XML fragment string.

```
$targetXml = <<<'XML'
<mytag Someattribute="anything">
   here I want to put my tag
...
a lot of tags
...
</mytag>
XML;

$fragmentXml = <<<'XML'
<othertag>with text</othertag>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($targetXml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// fetch the first mytag node that has a Someattribute
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//mytag[@Someattribute][1]') as $targetNode) {
  // create a new fragment
  $fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
  // append the stored xml string to the fragment node
  $fragment->appendXml($fragmentXml);
  // insert the fragment before the first child of the target node
  $targetNode->insertBefore($fragment, $targetNode->firstChild);
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mytag Someattribute="anything"><othertag>with text</othertag>
   here I want to put my tag
...
a lot of tags
...
</mytag>
```

If you XML string is a whole document you need to load it as a separate document instance and import the document element.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//mytag[@Someattribute][1]') as $targetNode) {
  $import = new DOMDocument();
  $import->loadXml($fragmentXml);
  $targetNode->insertBefore(
    $document->importNode($import->documentElement, TRUE),
    $targetNode->firstChild
  );
}
```